# hide SubReport from Main report if there is no records in SubReport

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a `Main report` with around 10 `Sub-Reports` in `Tablix` row.

Now, I want to hide/suppress `Sub-Report` if the `Sub-Report` `Dataset` returns `No records`.

Below is example:

[image]

How can I solve it?

I'm using `SSRS-2008R2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Thanks for the viewed my question!*

Finally, I did some tricky work as below.

I don't know it's good as performance wise or not but I have created **`Sub-Report's DataSet`** on **`Main Report`** and then on **`Row-Visibility`** I have used below **`Expression`**

**`=IIF(CountRows("SubReportDatasetName") > 0 ,False,True)`**

**1.** 
 ***Right click on Row***

[image]

**2.** ***Set expression.***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution. Add this expression to the Tablix of sub report:

```
IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) = 0,True,False)
```

It will hide it in subreport in mainreport if no rows are present in subreport.